# How can I add an option to a <select> with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have the following HTML:

```
<select id="AccountID" name="AccountID">
<option value="02">AA</option>
<option value="01">BB</option>
<option value="00">CC</option>
</select>
```

Is it possible to use jQuery to insert another option to make it like this?

```
<select id="AccountID" name="AccountID">
<option value="99">Select Account ..</option>
<option value="02">AA</option>
<option value="01">BB</option>
<option value="00">CC</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `prepend` method:

```
$('#AccountID').prepend('<option value="99">Select Account ..</option>');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NJ8Bv/

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
$('#AccountID').prepend('<option value="99">Select Account..</option>');
```

OR

```
$("#AccountID").prepend(new Option("Select Account..", "99"));
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/NJ8Bv/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using html markup where possible. Try this:

```
$('#select').append($("<option></option>").attr("value",'my_val').text('This is my option'));
```